# Disallow search engine crawlers but allow google analitics

Tags: google-analytics, web-crawler, search-engine, robots.txt

It looks like my Google Analytics doesn't work because I have blocked all user-agents. My site is still in beta version, so I don't want to be visible to search engines, but I still want to watch my site analytics data.

How can I just allow Google Analytics in my robots.txt?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you resolve it? Before that post I was pretty sure that robots.txt params are blocking google analytics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to specify Google Analytics in your robots.txt.

Since Google Analytics is called for via javascript (the code you copy / paste) to your file, whenever somebody visits your page, it connects to the google analytics and registers the visit.

Robots.txt is only if you want to block Google bot from indexing your website (crawling it and posting it to google).

Comment: hmm, then my problem because my analytics don`t work is not about my robots.txt file...